# Update Arraylist with new record

Tags: android, arraylist, custom-arrayadapter

i want to update a new row automatically when there is new record in database how should i proceed using this custom array list method please help

I am using `arraylist.add(some_value)`
Thanks in advance

Comment: This really isn't enough to be able to answer. What exactly is the issue that you are facing? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Read concepts of LiveData, or observers

Comment: there is no error

Comment: the problem is i want to update a row of array in my list view when the row of database is updated

Comment: which database?